# How to Auto update Value in mongodb Document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose-schema

I have a field in my mongoose schema called **"active"** and I wanted to know if there is any way that every date expired in a particular document, then the **"active"** field would change to **false**. how should I do that if so, What is the easiest way to do this? else, what is recommended?

And below is my Schema;

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const schema = new Schema({

user_id: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},
firstName: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},
username: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},
email: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},
hash: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},
active: {
    type: Boolean,
},

role: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},
createdDate: {
    type: Date, 
    default: Date.now

}
});

schema.set('toJSON', { virtuals: true });

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', schema);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a feature in mongo called `Change Streams` that allow you to access real-time data changes. You can subscribe to the changes of a single collection or the whole database and react to them. You can also filter for specific changes or transforms. For your case an example would be something like this.

EDIT: Change streams implementation is only available on replica sets.

```
const pipeline = [
  { $match: { expire_date: {$lt: Date.now()} } },
  { $set: { active: false } }
];

const collection = db.collection('user');
const changeStream = collection.watch(pipeline);
changeStream.on('change', next => {
  // process next document
});
```

Comment: I tried this but I have an issue called **MongoError: The $changeStream stage is only supported on replica sets**  @C.Gochev    here is the code I added to my schema `const pipeline = [
    { $match: { createdDate: {$lt: Date.now()} } },
    { $set: { active: false } }
  ];
  const collection =  mongoose.model('User', schema);
  const changeStream = collection.watch(pipeline);
  changeStream.on('change', next => {
    // process next document
  });`

Comment: Yes, forgot to mention that you can only do it on a replica set. Here is an instruction how to run one https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/convert-standalone-to-replica-set/

Comment: Thanks, u  very much I will proceed according to your instructions.

Comment: Okay sure  i will, cause its help me

Comment: @C.Gochev where do we apply the change stream implementation? should it be in the schema file or in a server function?

Comment: @Haroon Azhar Khan if by server function you mean a route in a web server it's definitely not a good idea also I wouldn't use the schema file either. Maybe a separate file that you require in the entry point of your program: )